# Cannot import XSSF in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am referencing the version 3.7 of the Apache POI and I am getting a "cannot be resolved" error when I do:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Other import statements that reference POI *DO NOT* give me errors, such as:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
```

Any ideas??

Comment: I was getting the same problem, it seems to be rooted in the poi-3.whatever.jar file not having the xssf packed inside for some reason

Answer (score 235):

For OOXML to work you need the POI-OOXML jar which is separately packaged from the POI jar.

Download the POI-OOXML jar from the following location -

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.11/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar

For Maven2 add the below dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. For me (version 3.11) I simply needed to add an additional jar: poit-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar. I did not realize there was no tie between them. Thanks for the answer Pushkar +1.

Answer (score 39):

The classes for the OOXML file formats (such as XSSF for .xlsx) are in a different Jar file. You need to include the poi-ooxml jar in your project, along with the dependencies for it

You can get a list of all the components and their dependencies on the POI website [here](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

What you probably want to do is download the [3.11 binary package](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), grab the `poi-ooxml` jar from it, and the dependencies in the `ooxml-lib` directory. Import these into your project and you'll be sorted.

Alternately, if you use Maven, you can [see here](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for the list of the artificats you'll want to depend on, but it'd want to be something like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The poi-ooxml maven dependency will pull in the main POI jar and the dependencies for you automatically. If you want to work with the non-spreadsheet formats, you'd also want to depend on the `poi-scratchpad` artifact too, as detailed on the [POI components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

Answer (score 20):

I added below contents in app "build.gradle"

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
```

Comment: it's really helped

Answer (score 8):

If you use Maven:

**poi => poi-ooxml in artifactId**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using POI 3.12 final (`3.12`) rather than the beta

Answer (score 7):

**I Got the Solution Guys**

You need to keep some points in your mind .

1. There are two different dependency one is (**poi**) & other dependency is (**poi-
   ooxml**) but make sure you must use poi-ooxml dependency in your code.
2. Just Add the following dependency in pom.xml & Save it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

3 .After you have saved the pom.xml then you need to try a small thing ,Use
(.) operator will try to import/fetch it & finally will not see any sort of error
because now it has imported that thing in your package.

Sample Code to Understand Better !!

```
package ReadFile;// package   
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;  // automatically added to your code after importing
public class Test          
{  
public static void Hello() // Method  
{  
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();   
}  
}
```

I tried my best to give you the solution , If you face any issue comment here i will try
to solve it .

Keep Learning Guys !!

Answer (score 6):

Problem: While importing the " org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"class showing an error in eclipse.

Solution: Use This maven dependency to resolve this problem:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

-Hari Krishna Neela

Answer (score 3):

Actual for 06.11.2021 days:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

1) imported all the JARS from POI folder
2) Imported all the JARS from ooxml folder which a subdirectory of POI folder
3) Imported all the JARS from lib folder which is a subdirectory of POI folder

```
String fileName = "C:/File raw.xlsx";
File file = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
Workbook workbook = null;
Sheet sheet;
Iterator<Row> rowIterator;
try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        System.out.println(fileExtension);
        if(fileExtension.equals(".xls")){
        workbook  = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream));
        }
        else if(fileExtension.equals(".xlsx")){
        workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Wrong File Type");
        } 
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        //Check the cell type after evaluating formulae
       //If it is formula cell, it will be evaluated otherwise no change will happen
        switch (evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()){
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
        break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
        break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        Not again
        break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        break;
        }
}
 System.out.println("\n");
}
//System.out.println(sheet);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}​
```

Comment: Row is not importing...can you share the jar file link please

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I dug through the poi-3.17.jar file and there was no xssf package inside.

I then went through the other files and found xssf int the poi-ooxml-3.17.jar

So it seems the solutions is to add

```
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
```

to your project, as that seems to make it work (for me at least)

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple things,what really worked was:
1. downloading "poi" and "poi-ooxml" manually
2.Adding these d/w jars into "Maven Dependencies"

Answer (score 1):

### If you use Maven:

Add the poi and the poi-ooxml dependency to make it work :)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>${poi-ooxml.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not described the environment, anyway, you should download apache poi libraries. If you are using eclipse , right click on your root project , so properties and in java build path add external jar and import in your project those libraries :

xmlbeans-2.6.0 ; poi-ooxml-schemas- ... ; poi-ooxml- ... ; poi- .... ;

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following files for my implementation:

- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.20160307.jar
- commons-codec-1.10.jar (this was in "lib" folder of the zip file you
  get from apache)
- curvesapi-1.03.jar (in "ooxml-lib" folder)
- poi-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (in "ooxml-lib" folder)

(though honestly, I'm not completely sure they are all necessary...)  It's a little confusing because they are packaged that way.  I needed to place them manually in my own "lib" folder and then add the references...

Maven always seems to download more than I need, so I always place libaries/dlls and things like that manually.

Comment: Apache POI [provides a handy page explaining what jars are needed for what](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), and everything you need comes in the binary download, so it doesn't have to be confusing or a mystery!

Comment: that page is handy if you're going to use Maven, but I prefer to add dependencies manually.  The page doesn't list everything separately.  Some of them aren't noticable at build time, but you'll find them by checking exceptions at run-time.  My implementation imports XLS and XLSX files into a jtable.  The above seemed to be all that was required for that.

Comment: Everything listed there is shipped in the binary download! Both what jars the components need, and what dependencies the jars need

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**NOTE:** If your project still cannot find the dependecy, add  the following line in your module-info.java:

```
requires poi.ooxml;
```