# POI-OOXML dependency not recognized

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I want to create an .xlsx workbook. Following instructions from tutorials and other Stackoverflow questions such as the following

[Cannot import XSSF in Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878341/cannot-import-xssf-in-apache-poi)

I added the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

My piece of code to convert a multipart file to xlsx workbook is the following:

```
 public void readExcelWorkbook(EuropeanAwards euApp, MultipartFile file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {

        File excelFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(excelFile);
        FileInputStream fIP = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP);


    }
```

The following import:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
```

is not recognized. 
I tried to add the poi-ooxml-schemas depencency instead but the import is still not recognized. Note that the hssf files are correctly recognized when adding the corresponding import:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Weird. I cannot reproduce this experiment: When trying your same dependency and code, Maven downloaded the poi-ooxml-3.12 artifact, and so, the import is well recognized. Are you sure that you have in your classpath the poi-ooxml-3.12.jar?

Comment: Can you try with a very simple pom? It might be that you've added some broken plugins or something

Comment: I pulled the project from a colleague and everything went ok. No idea what was the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you havent rebuild your maven project after adding the dependency. Try to clean and build the project.

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: I have cleaned and built the project but issue persists